# Is there a way to write asynchronous code/function without any involvement of Web APIs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous-javascript

I know it sound stupid because javascript is single threaded but can't help thinking about a function which takes unusual amount time with no involvement from web APIs like this

```js
console.log("start")

function apple() {
  let appleCount = 10;
  while (appleCount < 1000000) {
    appleCount = appleCount + 10;
    appleCount = appleCount * 0.0000052
  }
}

apple();
console.log("end")
```

so is there a way to run this apple function asynchronously ... i tried running this code in browser but not getting any results... help me out..

Comment: Use a service-worker

Comment: Are you expecting output: "start, end, apple done" insted "start, apple done, end"? It's possible with async / await feature.

Comment: i am expecting start, end ,apple done... and i don't think it is possible with async / await

Comment: The only way to run something that is 100% plain Javascript so that it doesn't block the main thread is to run it in a different thread (in nodejs, to use a WorkerThread).  As you seem to know the main thread runs your Javascript in a single thread so anything that is just plain Javsacript occupies that single thread.  To have it not occupy that single thread, you have to run it in a different thread, either a WorkerThread or another process.

Comment: @AbHisheKThaKur, yes you right, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to run something that is 100% plain Javascript like your `apple()` function so that it doesn't block the main thread is to run it in a different thread (in nodejs, to use a WorkerThread) or in a different process.

As you seem to know the main thread runs your Javascript in a single thread so anything that is just plain JavaScript occupies that single thread while it is running. To have it not occupy that single thread and block the event loop, you have to run it in a different thread, either a `WorkerThread` or run it in another process.

---

One can use timing tricks such as `setTimeout(apple, 100)` or `setImmediate(apple)` or even `Promise.resolve().then(apple)` to change WHEN the code runs (delaying when it starts), but all these timing tricks do is change when the code starts running.  In all these cases, when it runs, it still blocks and occupies the main thread and blocks the event loop while its running.

---

FYI, there are many asynchronous operations in nodejs that are not necessarily web APIs.  For example, there are asynchronous file APIs and crypto APIs that are asynchronous and non-blocking.  So, your question should be modified to not refer just to web APIs, but any asynchronous API.

Comment: bro setTimeout  and setImmediate are part of web APIs

Comment: @AbHisheKThaKur - And, I'm explaining that EVEN with those APIs, it doesn't avoid blocking the single thread because all they do is change when the single thread gets blocked.  FYI, webAPIs is not a term with a well defined meaning in the world of nodejs.  It may have a meaning in a browser, but this is nodejs.  There are plenty of APIs in nodejs that are asynchronous and are not webAPIs under any definition such as crypto and file APIs.

Comment: @AbHisheKThaKur - Does this answer explain/answer your question?

Comment: just wanted to mention that in nodejs libuv uses 4 threads which makes it possible for crypto and file APIs work asynchronously ... Not sure though

Comment: @AbHisheKThaKur - Yes, those are OS native threads where nodejs runs the native code implementation of file and crypto APIs.   This is not plain Javascript running in those threads, but native C/C++ code. All non-blocking, asynchronous operations in nodejs have some native code portion that either uses non-blocking OS APIs (like networking) or runs in native OS threads.  They use the event loop to coordinate completion from these other threads back to the main Javascript thread.

Answer (score 0):

> so is there a way to run this apple function asynchronously?

If you don't want to wait until your apple function is complete, Then you can use **Async Functions**.

***NOTE:** Async/Promises **are not** true asynchronous.*

```js
console.log("start")

async function apple() {
  let appleCount = 10;
  while (appleCount < 1000000) {
    appleCount = appleCount + 10;
    appleCount = appleCount * 0.0000052
  }
}

apple().then(() => console.log("Apple completed"));
console.log("end")
```

**But** If you want to run it on **another thread**, Then you should use **Workers**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Comment: Simply adding `async` to a `function` does not make it asynchronous. It just means the returned value will be auto-wrapped in a `Promise<T>` by the JS runtime.

Comment: @Dai Yes, I understand. It is not Really an Async, Because using the callbacks makes an async kind of illusion. If he doesn't want to wait until the `apple` function completes, `Async` functions works. But if he wants to run it as true async, Then Service Workers would be a great option.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to return promises.

```
function double(num) {
  return Promise.resolve(num * 2);
}

function add5(num){
  return Promise.resolve(num + 5);
}

double(1)// 2
    .then(add5)// 7
    .then(double)// 14
    .then(console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to create asynchrony in JavaScript without using built-in or platform APIs. That's what he's asking:

```js
function scheduleTask(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 0);
}

scheduleTask(() => {
  console.log("This is an asynchronous task");
});

console.log("This is the main JavaScript thread");
```

As you can see. I still had to use setTimeout or other APIs to simulate asynchronous tasks and such.